# IntelliJ not showing code coverage for class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, intellij

I'm having trouble with identifying code coverage in IntelliJ for my Apex class. On the side of my project, after activating "Run with Coverage," the percentage of lines covered is shown:

[image]

But the coverage summary doesn't seem to reflect that at all (View --> Tool Windows --> Coverage):

[image]

I feel that this may have something to do with being able to see my code coverage highlights per line. The same class which I need to get coverage for does not have any highlighted lines despite the lines covered telling me there is 90% coverage:

[image]

My question to you is how would I be able to see this class in the Coverage window and see the highlights for the code I have/haven't covered yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anthony. As Phil stated, it's definitely best to ask questions about Illuminated Cloud in the [public discussion groups](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!overview), [public issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/RoseSilverSoftware/illuminatedcloud/issues?status=new&status=open), or via support email (support@illuminatedcloud.com) just because I see all of those immediately whereas I don't necessarily see things here as quickly/easily.

Given that StackExchange is not intended to be product support forum, would you mind reposting via one of those channels so that I can help you with this issue? What you're showing in your screenshots definitely doesn't look correct. I just don't want to use StackExchange as a back-and-forth discussion forum until we can determine what's happening and how to resolve it for you.

Best regards,

Scott Wells

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get an answer about the capabilities and usage of Illuminated Cloud is via the dedicated forums:

- [Q&A](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!forum/qanda)
- [General discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!forum/discussion)